# Is there a way to have multi-level key binds in IDA?

Tags: ida

For example, in Visual Studio we can have 2-level key shortcuts: Alt+E,F to format selection, for example. In IDA when I press record and press Alt+E,F, it does record it, but the action is triggered as soon as I press Alt+E, and also if I bind another command to this shortcut Alt+E,F, only the first command is triggered when I Press Alt+E.